# Image Reference issue in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am creating a line chart in one view(myChartView) and saving it as _ChartFiles/chart01.jpg.
var filePathName = "_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg";

Which is saving at /views/myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg . Now in the very next line making a reference it as

`<img src="@filePathName" />`

but this is not displaying the image. what would be correct way to refer it?

Comment: just confirm the path of image...

Comment: filePathName = "_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg";
And images resides at /views/myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg. And reference is _ChartFiles/chart01.jpg

Comment: what is root directory here to refer the img file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want some static files to be accessed directly by the client, you cannot store them in the `~/Views` folder because by default (for security reasons) the server would not serve content from this folder.

See `~/Views/Web.Config`:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Try to save the files in other directory like `~/Static`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew Views was a conventionned folder in MVC but was not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You should save it in another folder than "Views" because in MVC this is a folder conventionned for HTML view and no other content, try to save it in "fonts" or whatever else,
and it would be :

```
<img src="fonts/yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: "Though, dunno why but using GIF or PNG is more supported than jpg" <<     There is no greater/lesser support in asp.net MVC for JPG as there is for GIF or PNG. Dont know where you got this from?

Comment: When I had some issue adding an image for the first time in html page I searched around in the web and saw that few people were saying it was better to use png for static images but maybe this is false today

Comment: I changed the code as
<img src="~/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg" />
and its started working. Means with variable it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the image path as

```
filePathName = "../views/myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg";
```

or

```
filePathName = "~/views/myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg";
```

Comment: the path folder was Views/_ChartFiles/smth.jpg and I'm nearly sure that ../ ~/ refers to something outside the whole project

Comment: hope this will work ../views/myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg

Comment: filePathName = "~/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg";
Does not worked but there is chart01.jpg resides.

Comment: I have faced same issue and it worked for me as  "../views/myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this one
filePathName = "myChartView/_ChartFiles/chart01.jpg";
<img src="@filePathName" />
```

Comment: Explain your code with little Explanation. Code only answers are not appreciated.